# error: opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert some MKV to MP4 with ffmpeg, and I keep getting the error below. Any thoughts?

I have installed ffmpeg and installed:

```
sudo apt install -y libopus-dev libmp3lame-dev libfdk-aac-dev libvpx-dev libx264-dev yasm libass-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev mercurial cmake
```

Command I ran with output:

```
ffmpeg -i 'video.mkv' -codec copy 'video.mp4' -strict -2 -y
ffmpeg version 4.0.2-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared

[mp4 @ 0x560e85326100] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0x560e85326100] opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Experimental feature
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I also tried adding `-strict -2` to no avail.

Comment: "opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it."

Comment: I did that also. Same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [order of options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) is important:

```
ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

Your example has trailing options which are often ignored.

In your case you are trying to mux Opus audio into the MP4 container, but outdated versions of `ffmpeg` consider this to be experimental. So you have to add `-strict experimental` or `-strict -2`. Use:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 'video.mkv' -codec copy -strict -2 'video.mp4'
```

Recent versions (FFmpeg 4.3 and newer & the git master branch) [no longer need](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=ca7a192d104f08a4dbfda31a6c4f29a1f05074ad) `-strict -2` / `-strict experimental` to mux Opus into MP4:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 'video.mkv' -codec copy 'video.mp4'
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone encounters the no-audio problem after using `-strict -2` option, you could try to use `-c:a aac` option after `-c copy` like this:

`ffmpeg -y -i 'input.mkv' -c copy -c:a aac 'output.mp4'`

Comment: Thanks that worked for me!, But what happens if i have more than 1 audio channel? How can i force ffmpeg to copy a specific audio track?